# How can I apply formatting to specific menu items or keys or directories in menukeys?

Tags: tikz-pgf, menukeys

For example, is it possible to color the last item in a menu from the `menukeys` package? Is there a way to make a macro out of making every last item in menu bold? I would like this macro to work globally.

It would be nice to know how to interact directly with each component in menus and directories.

The example from the `menukeys` Manual, 2014/03/10 — v1.3 page 9:

> The more advanced command is \newmenustyle. It has nine arguments:
>   `\newmenustyle⟨* ⟩{⟨name⟩}[⟨pre⟩]{⟨first⟩}
>   [⟨sep⟩]{⟨mid⟩}{⟨last⟩}{⟨single⟩} [⟨post⟩]{⟨theme⟩}`.
>
> Example: `\newmenustyle{mystyle}[$\bullet$]{draw,red}[$\ast$]%
>          {draw}{draw,red}{draw,dashed}[$\bullet$]`

results in:

> Runaway argument? ./menukeystest.tex:11: Paragraph ended before \tw@declare@sytle@extra@args was complete.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\renewmenumacro{\directory}[/]{paths}
\renewmenumacro{\menu}[>]{roundedmenus} % default: menus
\renewmenumacro{\directory}{pathswithfolder} % default: paths
\renewmenumacro{\keys}{shadowedroundedkeys} % default: roundedkeys
% \newcommand{\button}[1]{{\renewmenumacro{\keys}{roundedkeys}\keys{#1}}}
% better/official:
\newmenumacro{\button}[+]{roundkeys}

\begin{document}

\menu{Macros>AppleScript>Show Files}

\menu{Macros>AppleScript>Show Files} <-- Color last item

\menu{Macros>AppleScript>\textbf{Show Files}} <-- Make last item bold

\directory{/home/user/Desktop}

\keys{SHIFT + H}

\button{Start Process}

\end{document}
```

## Simulated Output

[image]

Comment: The font is bold, in my point of view

Comment: Untested, but see the menukeys documentation, section 'Declaring styles': **last**
is the style for the last list element.

Comment: @Marijn I think there is a problem with the documentation, because the example does not work. It does not demonstrate how to implement `mystyle`. I defined it using the example and implemented like this: `\renewmenumacro{\menu}[>]{roundedmenus,mystyle}`

Comment: @macmadness86 you are right about the example in the manual, it has eight arguments while there should be nine - adding, e.g., {grey} at the end resolves the error. I've edited your post (for future reference) to try to focus the question on the actual issue which is nicely illustrated by your MWE and desired output.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks. Edits are mostly fine. Although, I am not sure that the removal of the `last` key is helpful for future reference. Afterall, it is essential in formatting the last constituent in `\menu`.

Comment: @Marijn I tried `\newmenustyle{mystyle}[]{draw,red}[]{draw}{draw,red}{draw,dashed}[]{blue}` (9 total: 6 mandatory, 3 Optional) implemented -> `\renewmenumacro{\menu}[>]{roundedmenus,mystyle}`. It did not work.

Comment: @macmadness86 `\renewmenumacro` takes only one style as argument, e.g., `\newmenustyle{mystyle}[]{draw,red}[]{draw}{draw,red,fill=blue!60}{draw,dashed}[]{grey}` combined with `\renewmenumacro{\menu}[>]{mystyle}` to color the last element. However, the results do not look as nice as the styles provided by the package, therefore the solution by @salim-bou is probably a better approach.

Comment: You should use `\newmenumacro{\button}[+]{roundkeys}` instead of your definition. Furthermore there’s a group missing in your definition, so that the change of `\keys` isn’t in the right scope: i.e. the first use of `\button` will change all following `\keys` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a solution:

1. create two copy  `roundedmenusA` and `roundedmenusB` from `roundedmenus`.
2. modify those two styles to get the desired effects.

---

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\copymenustyle{roundedmenusA}{roundedmenus}
\copymenustyle{roundedmenusB}{roundedmenus}

\def\lastcolor{blue!50}

\makeatletter

% modify style roundedmenusA

\tw@declare@style*{roundedmenusA}{%
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
      \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,signal to=east]%
      {\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}[\hspace{-0.2em}\hspace{0em plus 0.1em minus 0.05em}]%
{%
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
      \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,signal from=west,signal to=east]%
      {\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}{%
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
      \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,signal from=west,fill=\lastcolor]%
      {\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}{%
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
      \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base]{\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}{gray}

% modify style roundedmenusB

\tw@declare@style*{roundedmenusB}{%
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
      \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,signal to=east]%
      {\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}[\hspace{-0.2em}\hspace{0em plus 0.1em minus 0.05em}]%
{%
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
      \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,signal from=west,signal to=east]%
      {\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}{%
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
      \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,signal from=west]%
      {\bfseries\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}{%
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
      \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base]{\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}{gray}

\makeatother

\renewmenumacro{\directory}[/]{paths}
\renewmenumacro{\menu}[>]{roundedmenus} % default: menus
\renewmenumacro{\directory}{pathswithfolder} % default: paths
\renewmenumacro{\keys}{shadowedroundedkeys} % default: roundedkeys
\newmenumacro{\button}[+]{roundkeys}

\begin{document}

\menu{Macros>AppleScript>Show Files}

\renewmenumacro{\menu}[>]{roundedmenusA}

\menu{Macros>AppleScript>Show Files} <-- Color last item

\renewmenumacro{\menu}[>]{roundedmenusB}

\menu{Macros>AppleScript>Show Files} <-- Make last item bold

\directory{/home/user/Desktop}

\keys{SHIFT + H}

\button{Start Process}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Note: you can also obtain the desired effects with `\changemenuelement` or `\renewmenustyle`, but problems of alignment  appear.

Comment: Why are there four nodes per style? Could you explain what is going on there?

Comment: @macmadness86: The four nodes are: **single** element, **first** of multiple elements, **last** of multiple elements and **others** in multiple elements (arguments not in this order).